# get current orientation in degree of mobile in android

Tags: android-orientation

I want to get current orientation of mobile in android. I can detect orientation change using OrientationEventListener. but this only work when there is a change in orientation. I want to do something when orientation is changed. But for some purpose I need  to know my current orientation if mobile is on the table and there is no orientation change. From some googling I found that sersormanager.getorientation and sensormanager.getRotationMatrix can be used for this purpose. But I can not implement it in code. Can anyone provide me some code to get my current orientation in degree?

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13817444/575643

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, you should have a look at the SensorManager.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

here is a nice sample, look at onAccuracyChanged() :

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/43.html