# Android I want to get rotation angle for device

Tags: android, orientation

For example, I started application then device  is turned 90 degree by side.I want to detect this event for each planes on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SensorManager and TYPE_GYROSCOPE/TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR/TYPE_ORIENTATION/ to get these value.

Look [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) for details.

Comment: Post a solution not a link, this link could be broken in a future e.g. that answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/13817444/575643

Comment: Kindly add a proper solution like the other answer.

Comment: check this out https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position#sensors-pos-orient

Answer (score 19):

You can get the screen orientation (for example in your onResume() Method) like this:

```
private static final int ORIENTATION_0 = 0;
private static final int ORIENTATION_90 = 3;
private static final int ORIENTATION_270 = 1;





Display display = ((WindowManager)
          getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int screenOrientation = display.getRotation();

switch (screenOrientation)
{
default:
case ORIENTATION_0: // Portrait
   // do smth.
break;
case ORIENTATION_90: // Landscape right
   // do smth.
break;
case ORIENTATION_270: // Landscape left
   // do smth.
break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to get for X,Y,Z of planes of phone. This is a solution for Z plane.It does not cover others.

Comment: If you want to check all 3 planes then you can register a SensorEventListener and retreive the values in its "onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)" Method. For further Details look here: [SensorEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html) and here [SensorEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the sensor manager to calculate x,y,z on every point. and use equation to find angle between two points. consider your starting points (0,0,0);

Answer (score 0):

You can use **OrientationEventListener** for the planes

```
OrientationEventListener mOrientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(
            getApplicationContext()) {
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {

        }
    };

    if (mOrientationListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
        mOrientationListener.enable();
    }
```