# How to get angle by which an android device rotated?

Tags: android

I want to make a compass app for my android phone in which an image of compass will rotate and show the direction change, I googled and found some tutorials like on codeofninja.com and javadecodegeeks.com but none of them are working on my device(I have Samsung S3 phone).
I am totally stuck in how do i get the angle of rotation and show the change of direction by rotation of an image. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You Can see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html

http://www.workingfromhere.com/blog/2009/03/30/orientation-sensor-tips-in-android/

https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/43/using_the_sensors_api

and refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817444/2771869....

You can get the screen orientation (for example in your onResume() Method) like this:

```
private static final int ORIENTATION_0 = 0;
private static final int ORIENTATION_90 = 3;
private static final int ORIENTATION_270 = 1;


Display display = ((WindowManager)
          getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int screenOrientation = display.getRotation();

switch (screenOrientation)
{
default:
case ORIENTATION_0: // Portrait
   // do smth.
break;
case ORIENTATION_90: // Landscape right
   // do smth.
break;
case ORIENTATION_270: // Landscape left
   // do smth.
break;
}
```

Comment: Does this works? I don't want to write another code unless it works, i am now pretty frustrated :( so pls tell if u hv tried making compass app using this code?

Comment: If you want to check all 3 planes then you can register a SensorEventListener and retreive the values in its "onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)" Method. For further Details look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html and here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use orientation sensors of the device this is a simple class demonstrating how it can be used :

```
package com.samplecompass;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class CompassActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

  Float azimut;  // View to draw a compass

  public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      paint.setColor(0xff00ff00);
      paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
      paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
      paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    };

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      int width = getWidth();
      int height = getHeight();
      int centerx = width/2;
      int centery = height/2;
      canvas.drawLine(centerx, 0, centerx, height, paint);
      canvas.drawLine(0, centery, width, centery, paint);
      // Rotate the canvas with the azimut      
      if (azimut != null)
        canvas.rotate(-azimut*360/(2*3.14159f), centerx, centery);
      paint.setColor(0xff0000ff);
      canvas.drawLine(centerx, -1000, centerx, +1000, paint);
      canvas.drawLine(-1000, centery, 1000, centery, paint);
      canvas.drawText("N", centerx+5, centery-10, paint);
      canvas.drawText("S", centerx-10, centery+15, paint);
      paint.setColor(0xff00ff00);
    }
  }

  CustomDrawableView mCustomDrawableView;
  private SensorManager mSensorManager;
  Sensor accelerometer;
  Sensor magnetometer;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mCustomDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this);
    setContentView(mCustomDrawableView);    // Register the sensor listeners
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
      accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    magnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
  }

  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
  }

  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
  }

  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {  }

  float[] mGravity;
  float[] mGeomagnetic;
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
      mGravity = event.values;
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
      mGeomagnetic = event.values;
    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
      float R[] = new float[9];
      float I[] = new float[9];
      boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
      if (success) {
        float orientation[] = new float[3];
        SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
        azimut = orientation[0]; // orientation contains: azimut, pitch and roll
      }
    }
    mCustomDrawableView.invalidate();
  }
}
```

you need this permissions to make this work  :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Then if you want to rotate an image using the device's orientation you need to use Matrix this is a simple example :

```
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

So , use the SensorManager to get the orientation and the Matrix to turn your image . I didn't try it really but it is in this aspect , Good Luck